# Apply form_hook on my form

Tags: drupal, hook

If the hook is called `hook_field_settings_form($field, $instance, $has_data)`, my module is called `mymodule`. How can I use this hook on my form?
I would guess `mymodule_field_settings_form($field, $instance, $has_data)`. But it's a address field (`<div class="myformclass" id="myformid">`) in a form. How can I apply this function to only my address field?

**EDIT**:
What I'm trying to achieve here is the following thing. I have a create content page and in this page, you can fill in an address. I want to make some field of this address required and some are not required. So I figured out, I need the `hook_field_settings_form`-hook... Right?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what it is you want to do... you want to use hook_form or hook_field_settings_form? What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Ok, I'll try again. See my edit.

Comment: You don't want `hook_field_settings_form`, that provides a settings form for a module that implements a custom field. `hook_form_alter` is the way to go

Comment: @Clive, yes I do :-) (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8516724/drupal-field-settings-form), could you answer that question too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use hook_form_alter

I used this myself to make the title field not required as I did not want it to be visible.
Important to use the if statement otherwise it will try to alter every form that you load. I am not sure what drupal version you have but this is drupal 7 even though other versions are pretty similar.

```
/**
 * 
 * Form Alter Widget
 * 
 */
 function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if($form_id == 'myformid') {
    $form['title']['#required'] = false;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you mean is hook_form_FORMID_alter. Notice the form ID is between the form and the alter.