# Drupal field_settings_form

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, field

I made my own Field in Drupal for an address. It displays things like street, number, zip,... So far so good. But for some reason, ALL field are required. Although there are set required in the UI or the Array.

So I would like to edit it's field_settings_form. I found myself an example in the Drupal-core code, but it doesn't help me a lot. Goal of the field_settings is to make the fields visible or not and required or not. So I came up with this code (I got it from `user_reference.module`)

```
function mymodule_field_settings_form($field, $instance, $has_data) {
    $settings = array_keys($field['settings']);
    $form = array();
    $form['required_fields'] = array(
        '#type' => 'checkboxes',
        '#title' => t('Required fields'),
        '#default_value' => is_array($settings['required_fields'])
            ? array('required')
            : array(),
        '#options' => $settings,
    );
    return $form;
}
```

But I'm quite stuck here. Anyone with some experience in this matter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a lot of research and even more trial and error, I found this myself.
First, I need to fill the "Form Settings" page, so we can check whether or not the page should be visible/required.

```
function mymodule_field_settings_form($field, $instance, $has_data) {
    $address_fields = array_keys($field['columns']);

    // Get all the address values and put them in an array
    $options = array();
    foreach ($address_fields as $value) {
        $options[$value] = $value;
    }

    // Fill in the values in the dropdown
    $form = array();
    $form['required_fields']['#type'] = 'checkboxes';
    $form['required_fields']['#title'] =  t('Required fields');
    $form['required_fields']['#default_value'] = $field['settings']['required_fields'];
    $form['required_fields']['#options'] = $options;

    $form['visible_fields']['#type'] = 'checkboxes';
    $form['visible_fields']['#title'] =  t('Visible fields');
    $form['visible_fields']['#default_value'] = $field['settings']['visible_fields'];
    $form['visible_fields']['#options'] = $options;

return $form;
}
```

And in anther function, I stated this. `$element` calls a function which returns all the elements available. It carries the same values as `$options` in the function above. If the `'required_field'` is on, we make it required, if the `'visible_field'` isn't on, we unset it!

```
  $element = _mymodule_load_element_fields();

    foreach (array_keys($element) as $field_key) {
       $element[$field_key]['#default_value'] = isset($items[$delta][$field_key]) ? $items[$delta][$field_key] : '';        // Set default value
       $element[$field_key]['#required'] = $field['settings']['required_fields'][$field_key] != '0';

    // Set required property
    if ($field['settings']['visible_fields'][$field_key] == '0') {
        unset($element[$field_key]);
    }
```

I hope this helps you!

Comment: Very nice :) It would be nice if this sort of thing was handled for you by the core field API, I might think about raising an issue on Drupal.org for this actually. Well done for getting it sorted I'll probably try a method like this in future. You should accept this as the answer when you can as it should definitely help anyone else with the same issue

Comment: I definitely will! (But I have to wait 2 days ;)) I really hope this will help others out, since it was a real pain in the ass without having decent documentation or something similar!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the 'field' in this context is the collection of form elements as a whole, not each individual form element. When a 'field' is required there's no mechanism for specifying particular form elements within that should be required or not.

I haven't found a satisfactory solution to this yet (I've come up against it several times now), the best I've been able to do is to make the field not required and then hook into validation with [`hook_field_validate`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--field--field.api.php/function/hook_field_validate/7) and do my 'required' validation there. It's not ideal but it works:

```
function mymodule_field_validate($entity_type, $entity, $field, $instance, $langcode, $items, &$errors) {
  if ($field['type'] == 'the_field_type') {

    // Loop through field values
    foreach ($items as $delta => $item) {

      // Validate what you need to against the individual field columns
      if (empty($item['address_line_1'])) {
        $errors[$field['field_name']][$langcode][$delta][] = array(
          'error' => 'mymodule_address_error', 
          'message' => 'The first line of the address is required.',
        );
      }

      if (empty($item['town'])) {
        $errors[$field['field_name']][$langcode][$delta][] = array(
          'error' => 'mymodule_address_error', 
          'message' => 'The town of the address is required.',
        );
      }

      // And so on...
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Clive, thanks for your answer (again!) I think I found a solid solution myself! I'll post it in a minute!

Comment: @Michiel: Fantastic, really looking forward to seeing your solution :)

Comment: there you go. I hope it will make sense to you :)